Polyline in Google map android java
My app is crashing because of the error below. and I have attached the code where the error occurred. Please give some idea to it.
at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzc (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:2)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzae.zzs (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:3)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline.setEndCap (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:2)
And my code is
Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
.addAll(polyLatLongs));
            polyline.setEndCap(new RoundCap());
            polyline.setWidth(10);
            polyline.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            polyline.setJointType(JointType.ROUND);


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
